# Import documentation to Drupal site from CI pipeline

Tags: importing-exporting

We have a Drupal 8 site for various product documentation.

Documentation for APIs is generated from Markdown files, and we currently do not have a good way to get that content into Drupal. We create "fake" pages in Drupal that use Javascript to fetch HTML from an external site (Azure Storage containers). This documentation is updated for each release, and we'd like users to pick which version they want to see documentation for.

The generated documentation (mainly HTML and images) is created in continuous integration pipelines. Now we upload that to Azure Storage. But is it possible to upload it to Drupal instead?

I've looked at Drush and https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_git. But I cannot find any tutorial / example that shows how to use that for our scenario. However, I've found tutorials on migrating a complete site from staging to production, or migrate from Drupal X to Drupal Y.

How can I import content to Drupal?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  I see too many loose ends in that post. This can only lead to opinion based answers. Some will say Migrate, others will say fetch the content from an API on cron/queue and create nodes, others might say create a static sub-site from it. It depends what suits you best.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the loose ends comes from my loose knowledge with Drupal ;-) if I knew the right question I probably would have the answer too. The User documentation does not seem to cover importing content.

Where can I learn more about static sub-site? That sounds interesting.

Comment: If you want to migrate in content, the core has a robust migrate framework. There are Migrate plugins that exist to parse HTML in order to create nodes and field data.

Comment: @Kevin That sounds interesting too! Could you please give an answer here with more details on how to do that? Would using drush together with a configuration like https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-files-and-images get us in the right direction?

Comment: You'll need to consult the docs and examples for migrating as there are a lot. The migrate plus module has a plugin to support dom traversal/importing: https://www.drupal.org/node/3062058